# Cx_Freeze - How to Include Modules

Tags: python, include, cx-freeze

I've been having this problem with including things into my cx_Freeze script, what im trying to do is include easygui and sys, as i use them in my program. Any help would be appreciated!

Heres the code:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable


build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os"], "excludes": ["tkinter"] }


base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
base = "Win32GUI"

setup(  name = "ProgramGUI",
        version = "0.1",
        description = "My GUI application!",
        options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
        executables = [Executable("ProgramGUI.py", base=base)])
```

So really all i need to know is how to incorparate Includes[ "sys", "easyGUI" ] Into the setup script :D

Comment: What problem do you see? If you import them normally, it should automatically detect them to include.

Comment: I managed to gather that when i built it it said ?missing modules: Easygui imported from ___main___ And when i run the .exe it says no module named easygui, most likely refrencing the 1st line of code: import easygui as eg

Comment: That means it knows it should be including easygui, but isn't finding it to copy. Where/how is easygui installed?

Comment: easygui is installed At D:\easygui

Comment: If you start python where your setup script is, does `import easygui` work? You need to put it somewhere so that that works. I think it's normally something like `C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages`, but I don't use Windows, so have a look around.

Comment: Import easygui works, but i have easygui installed outside of the Python32 directory, so i'll put the folder in the python dir and see what happens.

Comment: Still didn't work, now its telling me a whole new lot of modules are missing,

? PIL imported from easygui
? StringIO imported from easygui
? Tkinter imported from easygui
?tkFileDialog imported from easygui 

And i also have the easygui folder in site-packages.

Comment: Just paste easyGUI.py into the build folder created by Cx_Freeze. It will work easily.

Answer (score 5):

Seriously, I think you just miss a small thing to tell cx_freeze to import easy_gui:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable


build_exe_options = {
    "packages": ["os", "sys"], 
    "excludes": ["tkinter"],
    "includes": ["easy_gui"] # <-- Include easy_gui
}

base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
base = "Win32GUI"

setup(  name = "ProgramGUI",
        version = "0.1",
        description = "My GUI application!",
        options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
        executables = [Executable("ProgramGUI.py", base=base)])
```

Comment: What's the difference between "packages" and "includes"?

Comment: `packages` is for packages as the name suggests, `includes` is for modules. For example, the module name A.B designates a submodule named B in a package named A.